# pgRouting：how to use reverse_cost？

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting, postgis-1.5

I add a new column, naming it "reverse_cost", and give it the same data in the shape_leng column.

[image]

But as I run the shortest path algorithm in pgadmin, I got an error message.

[image]

here's my sql code

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
            SELECT gid as id,
                     start_id::int4 AS source, 
                     end_id::int4 AS target,
                     shape_leng::double precision as cost
                    FROM network',
            10, 17, true, true);
```

and here's the error

```
Error:  Error, reverse_cost is used, but query did't return 'reverse_cost' column

********** Error **********

Error: Error, reverse_cost is used, but query did't return 'reverse_cost' column
SQL status: XX000
```

As I change the code to this one, everything went well,

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
            SELECT gid as id,
                     start_id::int4 AS source, 
                     end_id::int4 AS target,
                     shape_leng::double precision as cost
                    FROM network',
            10, 17, false, false);
```

[image]

so I want to know how to use reverse_cost in PostGIS？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included the reverse cost in the query that gets the data. Add that column and it should work:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
    SELECT gid as id,
        start_id::int4 AS source, 
        end_id::int4 AS target,
        shape_leng::double precision as cost,
        shape_leng::double precision as reverse_cost
        FROM network',
    10, 17, true, true);
```

Also, you're not even using the cost (nor reverse_cost) columns from your table, but just the shape_leng with an alias. If you want to use the actual columns, change to:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
    SELECT gid as id,
        start_id::int4 AS source, 
        end_id::int4 AS target,
        cost::double precision,
        reverse_cost::double precision
        FROM network',
    10, 17, true, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I edit your first code above like this：  `
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
    SELECT gid as id,
        start_id::int4 AS source, 
        end_id::int4 AS target,
        shape_leng::double precision as cost,
        rcost::double precision as reverse_cost
        FROM network',
    17, 10, true, true);`, but when I copy the second one you posted I got another error.